# Image.FromFile() or FromStream() hangs on GdiplusStartup

Tags: c#, .net, mono, xamarin

I have a simple C# Application containing this line:

```
var mImage = System.Drawing.Image.FromFile(filename);
```

When running this code on Windows (.NET), the image is loaded correctly.
When running the same code on OS X (Mono), the application just hangs. The debugger stays in that call forever. No exception no nothing.

The callstack shows the application hangs at:

> System.Drawing.GDIPlus.GdiplusStartup ()

What could go wrong here?

PS: I have the latest versions of Xamarin Studio and Mono installed.

Comment: Is this the standard .NET `Image`?

Comment: Yes, it is. I have just updated the question.

Comment: Is it just this one image file that causes the problem, or do you get the same hang regardless of which file you try to open? Does the image get loaded as expected (i.e. looks correct, no artifacts) when you load it on Windows?

Comment: At least work down the google hits from "osx gdiplusstartup hang".

Comment: Guess what I did before asking this question. I could not find a solution to my problem there.

Comment: The top result of that search, at this time, is [this other question on StackOverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9423560/c-sharp-mono-new-bitmapfilename-just-hangs-on-osx), which suggests it doesn't actually hang, it just takes a really long time. How have you determined that "forever" is really "forever"?

Comment: Well, I waited at least 2 minutes. That's pretty much unacceptable (even if it's not "forever").

Comment: how large is the image?

Comment: Can you provide the image you use? If not, can you find another, public, image that exhibits the problem?

Comment: I tried with several images. Mostly small PNGs or JPEGs (< 100kb).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1) Not only check you have the latest Xamarin Studio version but **check you have the latest build!!!**

**Bug report:**

This problem was reported by Troy Dawson using **Xamarin Studio Version 5.5 (build 198)**, just over a month ago: https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23444

> "With the latest Mono from the alpha release channel, attached project
>   should raise an typenotfound exception when run at:
>
> ```
> var image = Image.FromStream(content);
> ```
>
> Because GDIPlus can't be initialized or something.
>
> This is similar to another bug I filed where Image.FromStream() takes
>   a very long time to return when Mono is first run."

**Full exception:**

> An exception was thrown by the type initializer for
>   System.Drawing.GDIPlus ---> System.Exception: GdiplusStartup

**Solution:**

A day after the bug was reported on 2014-09-29 Sadik Ali confirms he can reproduce the problem [Comment 1](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23444#c1), then 4 days later Troy Dawson confirms that **Xamarin Studio Version 5.5 (build 227) fixes the issue** [Comment 2](https://bugzilla.xamarin.com/show_bug.cgi?id=23444#c2).

---

2) If it still fails with the latest build I suggest you go through the limitations and make sure the image(s) you're loading are supported:
https://github.com/mono/libgdiplus/blob/master/TODO

Answer (score 3):

The problem is MonoMac GDI's way of interfacing with Mac fonts. The first time it is launched, it builds a font-cache it needs, and this actually takes a few *minutes*. Just let it run for a while. This delay goes away once the font cache is built.

If you kill it, it never finishes building the cache, and it'll happen every time. It's a shame they don't even yet have any kind of dialog or message printed that this is happening.

In rare situations, your font-cache directory may not be writable by mono. In this case, you can either run the app as root once, or you can follow the [instructions here](https://forums.xamarin.com/discussion/comment/54558#Comment_54558).

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably performance. You code should run fine; the image is just taking a longer time to load, this is due to mono's `System.Drawing` being just a C# wrapper

Sadly mono's System.Drawing has major issues providing all features in `System.Drawing`. Windows works well because it uses the native GDIPlus.dll but you code may not work well in unix-based systems.

[See more info about mono's System.Drawing here](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/gui/drawing/)

Depending on how you are using it, there are better alternatives to System.Drawing.

MonoMac suggests [Mono.Cairo](http://www.mono-project.com/docs/tools+libraries/libraries/Mono.Cairo/)

[This StackOverFlow post may be useful as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1528525/alternatives-to-system-drawing-for-use-with-asp-net)

Comment: But, really; two minutes to load what I assume is a small image (perhaps I shouldn't assume that)?  That's not just slow, it's broken.

Comment: Give some of the alternatives I linked a try, and see if that improves things. This would not be the first time System.Drawing didn't work right on mono